# scalapb isn't returning channel when using plain test

Tags: scala, scalapb

i am trying to build a client using gRpc with scalaPB.  According to the documentation I should be able to run the following to create a channel:

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext(true).build
```

But when I the build method isn't recognized
This is because the following is returning an Any instead of a ManageChannelBuilder

```
val channelBuilder: Any = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 5000).usePlaintext(true)
```

Comment: It's the correct code. If you're using intellij, somehow intellij's java part cannot recognize grpc builder method's return type correctly, just fire build system and it should compile.

Comment: that was it, thank you